# Not able to run flink application which deserializes avro data coming from a kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro

Trying to read avro data from a kafka topic using a flink application. Getting the below error while running the flink app. This is my first time working with flink/kafka, and couldn't fix this from days.

> org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobInitializationException: Could not start the JobMaster.
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultJobMasterServiceProcess.lambda$new$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceProcess.java:97)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1609)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to rollback to checkpoint/savepoint s3://rinc-ingestion-service/flink-savepoints/namespaces/default/deployments/e8f1afd0-9236-43c2-93cb-db16604da594/1a6716af-6357-4ae3-95da-dad0bdb1f7cc/savepoint-f101ee-feb4e8023b09. Cannot map checkpoint/savepoint state for operator 7df19f87deec5680128845fd9a6ca18d to the new program, because the operator is not available in the new program. If you want to allow to skip this, you can set the --allowNonRestoredState option on the CLI.
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1606)
> ... 3 more
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to rollback to checkpoint/savepoint s3://rinc-ingestion-service/flink-savepoints/namespaces/default/deployments/e8f1afd0-9236-43c2-93cb-db16604da594/1a6716af-6357-4ae3-95da-dad0bdb1f7cc/savepoint-f101ee-feb4e8023b09. Cannot map checkpoint/savepoint state for operator 7df19f87deec5680128845fd9a6ca18d to the new program, because the operator is not available in the new program. If you want to allow to skip this, you can set the --allowNonRestoredState option on the CLI.
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.Checkpoints.throwNonRestoredStateException(Checkpoints.java:230)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.Checkpoints.loadAndValidateCheckpoint(Checkpoints.java:194)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.restoreSavepoint(CheckpointCoordinator.java:1648)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.tryRestoreExecutionGraphFromSavepoint(DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.java:163)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.java:138)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(SchedulerBase.java:335)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.(SchedulerBase.java:191)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.(DefaultScheduler.java:140)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultSchedulerFactory.createInstance(DefaultSchedulerFactory.java:134)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.createScheduler(DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.java:110)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createScheduler(JobMaster.java:346)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.(JobMaster.java:323)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.internalCreateJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:106)
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.lambda$createJobMasterService$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:94)
> at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedSupplier$4(FunctionUtils.java:112)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
> ... 3 more

The flink app code is below.

```
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.initializer.OffsetsInitializer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import testRecord.DataRecordAvro;
public class KafkaAvroDeserialize {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        KafkaSource<DataRecordAvro> source = KafkaSource.<DataRecordAvro>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("pkc-2396y.us-east-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092")
                .setTopics("test")
                .setGroupId("demo-consumer-avro-1")
                .setProperty(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "https://psrc-1wydj.us-east-2.aws.confluent.cloud")
                .setProperty("basic.auth.credentials.source", "USER_INFO")
                .setProperty("basic.auth.user.info", "5CDO5ZR4HDJSGOHT:v/YJxrw6iR+ASbIwMGefZN9SIzPccuyyTQC8EXFn8cOcJCeC1EASEfvHzFRflyXd")
                .setProperty("advertised.host.name", "pkc-2396y.us-east-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092")
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<>(DataRecordAvro.class))
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .build();
        DataStreamSource<DataRecordAvro> input = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");
        input.map(record -> "DESERIALIZED: " + record.getMsgType() + "-" + record.get(0) + "-" + record.get(1) + "-" + record.get(2)).print();
        env.execute("Printing the payload");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The clue is this entry from the logs:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to rollback to checkpoint/savepoint s3://rinc-ingestion-service/flink-savepoints/namespaces/default/deployments/e8f1afd0-9236-43c2-93cb-db16604da594/1a6716af-6357-4ae3-95da-dad0bdb1f7cc/savepoint-f101ee-feb4e8023b09. Cannot map checkpoint/savepoint state for operator 7df19f87deec5680128845fd9a6ca18d to the new program, because the operator is not available in the new program. If you want to allow to skip this, you can set the --allowNonRestoredState option on the CLI.

You've made changes to the job since it was last run, and as a result there's state in a checkpoint or savepoint that cannot be restored.

You'll want to read this section from the documentation -- https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/ops/state/savepoints/#assigning-operator-ids -- which explains the role played by operator IDs, and the importance of setting explicit IDs so that you can evolve how your job uses state without running into problems like this.

If you don't mind starting over from scratch (and abandoning whatever state your job has), then the easiest way forward is to resubmit the job without having it try to restart from a checkpoint or savepoint. In your case the only state is in the KafkaSource, so hopefully dropping the state won't be painful.